# Discord.js: DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating a bot using guide by Discord.js, however after like 3 or sometimes 3 commands the bot stops working and i get
[discord message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q1u9.png)
i have tried to restart it many times but after sometime it just stop working again and again

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path')
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Collection ,ActionRowBuilder,EmbedBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname,'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath,file);
    const command = require(filePath);

    if('data' in command && 'execute' in command){
        client.commands.set(command.data.name,command);
    }else{
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing`);
    }
}


client.once(Events.ClientReady, () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
})

//menu
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
            );
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0x0099FF)
            .setTitle('pong')
            .setDescription('Some description here')
            .setImage('https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1310339617/vector/ping-pong-balls-isolated-vector-illustration.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=sHlz5sbJrymDo7vfTQIuaj4lbmwlvAhVE7Uk_631ZA8=')

        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', ephemeral: true, embeds: [embed]});
    }
});
//======================================================================================================================

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand || 
        interaction.isButton() ||
        interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found`)
        return;
    }
    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    }catch(error){
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true});
    }
    console.log(interaction);
});
client.login(token);
```

[Error i get in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqUMR.png)

I wanted this bot to continue to execute commands as long as it's up and running

Comment: I see that you are using console.log() do you have any output of program tracing?  the error is stating that the request has already been acknowledged.  in your error message it states the issue is this line ( line 65) : await interaction.reply({content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common error in Discord.JS that occurs when you already replied to an interaction and you attempt to reply again.

From the discord.js discord server:

> You have already replied to the interaction.
>
> • Use .followUp() to send a new message
>
> • If you deferred reply it's better to use .editReply()
>
> • Responding to [slash commands](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#ephemeral-responses) / [buttons](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#responding-to-buttons) / [select menus](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#responding-to-select-menus)

To fix this error, you can use `.followUp()` to send another message to the channel or `.editReply()` to edit the reply as shown above.

You can see the documentation on a command interaction [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is that you cant reply to a slash command more then once in discords api so instead you should use

```
interaction.channel.send()
```

or

```
interaction.editReply()
```

Comment: `interaction.channel.send()` is the same as `interaction.followUp()`, if that makes up for any confusion

Comment: It's working decently now, Thank you sooo much