# The button on my command doesnt work right - Discord.js V14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a bot and made a command which should give a button when triggered, then when the button is clicked, the original message from the bot should be updated to "button was clicked". it does give the button but it says interaction failed. but when I click it again it then works.

and then when I run the command again, sometimes the bot just crashes, while sometimes it gives the button, after which it crashes.

I'm using discord.js V14

I've tried to make the command triggered by text and the first part works fine, but when it gets to the button part, it gets messed up. I'm still fairly new to discord.js v14 so the code is a bit of a mess.

This is the code:

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content === 'test') {
    let row = new ActionRowBuilder()
      .addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('test')
        .setLabel('testing')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
      );

    message.channel.send({
      content: 'hey there!',
      components: [row]
    });
  }

  client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) {
      message.channel.send('hello gringo');
    };
    if (interaction.customId)
      console.log(interaction);

    const filter = i => i.customId === 'test' && i.user.id === '877466540679786536';

    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
      filter,
      time: 15000
    });

    collector.on('collect', async i => {
      await i.update({
        content: 'Button was clicked!',
        components: []
      });
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
  })
});
```

and this is the error I get:

```
rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1064212307045003315/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTA2NDIxMjMwNzA0NTAwMzMxNTpJOGxpUEttZ2U3ZERIaW9iRXg4VkxiN2ZpREZJN2RRV2d6WW9uMUE3dXR2RFpNckI4SnliMEpCZGFEWm9qUVg0R2duS3ZTWk1UVkMyM015SWlKYk94cjU0Q3FWMVhCUFA5UDQzeWJVTzZPU09YNmZBR2NwS3MxZjRXeGgzOVAzSA/callback'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a common error in Discord.JS that occurs when you already replied to an interaction and you attempt to reply again.

From the discord.js discord server:

> You have already replied to the interaction.
>
> • Use .followUp() to send a new message
>
> • If you deferred reply it's better to use .editReply()
>
> • Responding to [slash commands](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#ephemeral-responses) / [buttons](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#responding-to-buttons) / [select menus](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#responding-to-select-menus)

To fix this error, you can use `.followUp()` to send another message to the channel or `.editReply()` to edit the reply as shown above.

You can see the documentation on a command interaction [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction)

Comment: You shouldn't copy-paste [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114210/6126373). If you think it's a duplicate, you can flag it as a duplicate instead. You can simply paste the URL of your previous answer.