# How to disable buttons after having an error in 'awaitModalSubmit' Discord Js

Tags: discord.js

I keep having a problem that I can't figure out.
For example, I use to wait for a reply in the modal function

```
awaitModalSubmit
```

```
await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
        time: 12000,
        filter: (i: { user: { id: string; }; }) => i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
        // @ts-ignore
    }).then(async (submitted) => {
      (buttons.components as any) = buttons.components.map((button: APIButtonComponent | 
       JSONEncodable<APIButtonComponent>) =>
        // @ts-ignore
        ButtonBuilder.from(button).setDisabled(true)
    );
    // @ts-ignore
    await submitted.update({components: [buttons]});
        submitted.followUp({
            content: 'Test'
        });
    }).catch(async (e: unknown) => {
      I can't disable the buttons here
    });
```

If I use the same code as in .then, I will not update the buttons, I will receive the following error

```
Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
```

Is there a way to disable the buttons I have in case I have an error in the modal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way i can fix my discord bot, which i\`m creating discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114210/15446076)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I can only update the buttons if I submitted to the modal.
If it enters the catch, I can no longer update..

Comment: Nvm, works, can you put this in an response? I want to give this answer Correct

Comment: Sorry but I'm not risking getting my answer flagged. If other people check out this post they can see the comments pretty easily though. Thank you for asking.