# "DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged." Throws this when ever i run a command on discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Throws the error "DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged." whenever i run a command through my discord server. I tried to look if i had multiple instances of the app running but no such thing. I have been using the discord.js guide for the main code.

I have tried to find other instances and looked through the code but the all it says is that it threw back an error due to the try catch method so not much help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interaction already acknowledged error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114210/15446076)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.